# How to compare characters of two text files using batch and replace it?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

i have a two text files named, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`

**file1.txt contains**

```
abc@d
```

**file2.txt contains**

```
abcad
```

How to compare both of them and leave the same letters as it is.. and only replace the part of symbols.. **for example :** replacing only 4th character which is @

**Note** : The position of the character will be varies..

**The code i used to get `file2.txt` output is,**

```
@echo off
cls
set /p input=type here:
echo %input% > file1.txt
set input0=!input:@=a!
echo %input0% >file2.txt
pause>nul
```

Comment: So you want `file2.txt` to be finally equal to `file1.txt`, right?